# Usage of Node JS with PHP in Real time Scenario

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, node.js, sockets

Basically I am a PHP Programmer. I would like to integrate PHP with Node js. I surfed in the google and got a sample project for chatting application using php and node js. I installed it to my local system and it is working fine. But, I am not able to understand the work flow i.e, how Node js helping php to work with.

This is the code in my nodeClient.js

```
var socket = io.connect( 'http://localhost:8080' );

$( "#messageForm" ).submit( function() {
    var nameVal = $( "#nameInput" ).val();
    var msg = $( "#messageInput" ).val();

    socket.emit( 'message', { name: nameVal, message: msg } );

    // Ajax call for saving datas
    $.ajax({
        url: "./ajax/insertNewMessage.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: { name: nameVal, message: msg },
        success: function(data) {

        }
    });

    return false;
});

socket.on( 'message', function( data ) {
    var actualContent = $( "#messages" ).html();
    var newMsgContent = '<li> <strong>' + data.name + '</strong> : ' + data.message + '</li>';
    var content = newMsgContent + actualContent;

    $( "#messages" ).html( content );
});
```

and in nodeserver.js

```
var socket = require( 'socket.io' );
var express = require( 'express' );
var http = require( 'http' );

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer( app );

var io = socket.listen( server );

io.sockets.on( 'connection', function( client ) {
    console.log( "New client !" );

    client.on( 'message', function( data ) {
        console.log( 'Message received ' + data.name + ":" + data.message );

        //client.broadcast.emit( 'message', { name: data.name, message: data.message } );
        io.sockets.emit( 'message', { name: data.name, message: data.message } );
    });
});

server.listen( 8080 );
```

i have this...

but i didnt understand the `socket.emit()` function and `socket.on()`.
In the socket.on() function, I understand that they are placing the result in a div.

But, In the index.php file they are using php, mysql query for getting the results and displaying it like this

```
<ul id="messages">
                    <?php 
                        $query = $pdo->prepare( 'SELECT * FROM message ORDER BY msgid DESC' );
                        $query->execute();

                        $messages = $query->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_OBJ );
                        foreach( $messages as $message ):
                    ?>
                        <li> <strong><?php echo $message->name; ?></strong> : <?php echo $message->message; ?> </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
```

without this php query the output won't come. I dont understand where is the node js helping out to run this application successfully.

Please help me on this, I hope that will solve many confusions regarding node js

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say from what you provided.

Node.js seems to be used here for realtime transmition only.

When you first load the page, php output the old (allready posted) messages from a table.
Later, when a new message is sended, php store it into the table (for later access) then send it to node.js which will then broadcast it to other clients.

Node.js don't seems to be used here for message persistency.

The exact behavior of node.js is hard to explain here. In a chat application it can be used as a push server (take a message as entry, then push it to other clients) but it has the capacity to be used as a full blown webserver too...

Comment: Hi, Thanks for giving me the reply. I am new to node.js, can you please help me with some example that shows the actual functionality of node.js with php in real time scenario.

Comment: the clear explanation about the above question , first in index.php page there is a form, after submitting the form data was sent to nodeClient.js, which i had given above. there the ajax call insert.php page,  there the insertion will go. then again, if you see the index.php page, there is a <ul id="messages"> tag, there we are again retrieving the info from the db and displaying it. This should fork fine without node js also. but, here we are using node js and I dont know, what exactly the node js is doing here. I hope you understand my problem

Comment: Insert.php is sending the message to node.js. Then node will push it to other clients in realtime (without page reload). That's exactly what I sayd in my original answer. What do you want me to add?

Comment: can you please provide me any example with real time scenario node js using php